# Printing a function that prints with ('around', 'each', 'text', 'and', 'variables')

Tags: python, function, output

Here is my code:

```
def icecream():
    cost = int(6)
    flavor = input('What flavor would you like? => ')
    return 'The', flavor, 'will cost', cost, 'dollars.'

print(icecream())
```

then after printing the output i get is:

```
What flavor would you like? => ('The', 'Vanilla', 'will cost', 6, 'dollars?')
```

I want the output to just simply read:

```
What flavor would you like? => The Vanilla will cost 6 dollars.
```

Comment: To explain **why** this happens: The function returns a tuple, so that's what was printed.

Answer (score 2):

When you `return` a comma-separated series of values, Python makes them into a tuple. The parenthesized output you see is that tuple.

If you want to do the equivalent of `print('The', flavor, 'will cost', cost, 'dollars.')`, where the individual items from the tuple are passed to the `print` function, you can do that with the `*` unpacking operator:

```
print(*icecream())
```

This is probably worse than formating a string, as the other answers suggest, but I thought it was worth including as an answer, since it seemed to me this was what you intended your current code to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use fstring

```
return f'The {flavor} will cost {cost} dollars'
```